# How do I separate strings in a variable and place them into new variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

`

I'm starting with a variable with chr strings.

df$Specs : chr [1:28752] "4 GB RAM | 64 GB ROM | ExpandableUpto256GB", "..."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXo7x.png)

My goal is to create 3 new variables called "RAM", "ROM", "ExpandableUpto" with the corresponding strings as row observations "xGBRAM", "xGBROM", "xExpandableUpto". Then I just remove the chr strings and be left with numbers as characters. Then I will convert them to numbers and transform them all to GB units.

Here's where I'm at currently.

df$RAM : chr [1:28752] "4GBRAM", "..."

df$ROM : chr [1:28752] "64GBROM", "..."

df$ExpandableUpto" : chr [1:28752] "ExpandableUpto256GB", "..."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvFpO.png)

I can get the chr strings into new variables "RAM" "ROM" and "ExpandableUpto" but since not all of the vectors have 3 sets of strings (some have 1 and 2), the strings fill the variables 1 at a time starting with "RAM". That means that some of my rows have "4GBROM" in the "RAM" variable. Is there a way to get only "RAM" strings in the "RAM" variable. etc?

What I started with:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTHrG.png)

remove whitespace in "Specs"

`Mobile_phones7 <- Mobile_phones6 %>%   mutate(Specs = stringr::str_remove_all(Specs, "\\s+"))`

remove "|" from chr strings from "Specs"

`Mobile_phones8 <- Mobile_phones7 %>%   mutate(Specs = stringr::str_split(Specs, coll("|")))`

split the character strings in "Specs" and place them in a list

of chr vectors of [1:3] strings.

`Mobile_phones9 <- Mobile_phones8 %>%   rowwise() %>%   mutate(Specs = Reduce(paste, Specs))`

separate Specs list vectors into 3 new variables separated by whitespace

`Mobile_phones10 <- Mobile_phones9 %>%   separate(Specs, c("RAM", "ROM", "ExpandableUpto"), sep = "\\s+")`

This resulted in:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oJCs.png)

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check updated code as per your comments

### data & code

```r
data.frame(spec=c("4 GB RAM | 64 GB ROM | ExpandableUpto256GB",
                  "6 GB RAM | 128 GB ROM", 
                  "128 GB ROM",
                  "0 MB ROM | Expandable Upto 32 GB",
                  "8 GB RAM | 128 GB ROM | Expandable Upto 1TB")) %>% 
  transmute(RAM=as.numeric(str_extract(spec, '\\d+(?=\\s\\w+\\sRAM)')),
         ROM=as.numeric(str_extract(spec, '\\d+(?=\\s\\w+\\sROM)')),
         ExpandableUpto=as.numeric(str_replace_all(str_extract(spec, '(?<=[Upto]).*\\d?'),'[:alpha:]',''))
         )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### output

```r
  RAM ROM ExpandableUpto
1   4  64            256
2   6 128             NA
3  NA 128             NA
4  NA   0             32
5   8 128              1
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my question except for converting TB to GB. Although I was able to figure it out. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

### code

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

data.frame(spec="4 GB RAM | 64 GB ROM | ExpandableUpto256GB") %>% 
tidyr::extract(col=spec, into = c('RAM', 'ROM', 'ExpandableUpto'), regex = '(.*)\\|(.*)\\|(.*)', remove = T) %>% 
mutate(across(c(RAM,ROM,ExpandableUpto), ~ str_remove_all(.x,'\\s')))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### output

```r
     RAM     ROM      ExpandableUpto
1 4GBRAM 64GBROM ExpandableUpto256GB
```

Comment: This is helpful. The only issue is that for the rows in df$Specs that only have 1 or 2 strings separated by "|", the output is "NA". Some of the rows only have a GBRAM or a GBROM string. For example, df$Specs[10,6] = "6 GB RAM | 128 GB ROM"

Comment: if you can provide all combination data examples then I can update the code and resend to you

Comment: `df[c(10,19,1036)] `

Comment: [1] "6 GB RAM | 128 GB ROM" [2] "128 GB ROM" [3] "0 MB ROM | Expandable Upto 32 GB"

Comment: Some of the rows don't contain all three "RAM" "ROM" and "ExpandableUpto" strings separated by "|". For the rows that are like this I am trying to put "NA" in the respective column if the information isn't there. Most of the rows do contain all three, for example [2158] " 8 GB RAM | 128 GB ROM | Expandable Upto 1TB"

Comment: My ultimate goal is to mutate these rows into 3 columns "RAM" "ROM" and "ExpandableUpto" and then remove the chr strings and convert to numerical and convert all units into GB. So the rows will contain numbers of GB only.